# How to write a forward function template?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I want understand more how `std::forward` works and how Explicit Template Arguments & Template Argument Deduction work along with Forwarding references, I've tried this example:

```
template <typename T>
T&& fwd_(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& arg){
    std::cout << "fwd_(type&)\n";
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

template <typename T>
T&& fwd_(typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& arg){
    std::cout << "fwd_(type&&)\n";
    ++arg;
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}

int main(){

    int&& l = fwd_<int>(5);
    int&& m = fwd_<int&&>(7);
    int& j = fwd_<int&>(m);
    int& k = fwd_<int&>(7); // UB?
    std::cout << k << std::endl;

  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

- I don't know what happened to `k`? and how come I can pass an r-value as an l-value? (`fwd_<int&>(7)`)?

I am sure that that l-value reference is bound to the function template parameter; not to the argument passed.

I am also sure that that expression yields undefined behavior because that parameter is destroyed when `fwd_` returns.

- I've tried that and changed the optimization level so I got different values because of UB.
- Are my thoughts correct? And if so how could I write a clean and correct version that mimicks the library one `std::forward`? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know what happened to k? and how come I can pass an r-value as an l-value? `(fwd_<int&>(7))`?

Yes this is dangerous, since `T` is `int&` and return value `T&&`, as a result of [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing) we get `int& &&` → `int&`, i.e. you end up returning a reference to a temporary, which is not life-extended, thus causing UB after the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression (the `;`).

For this reason the C++ standard explicitly [excludes](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/forward#3) this usage from `std::forward`:

> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>& t) noexcept;`
> `template <class T> constexpr T&& forward(remove_reference_t<T>&& t) noexcept;`
> . . .
>
> **3 *Remarks:* If the second form is instantiated with an lvalue
> reference type, the program is ill-formed.**

And **libstdc++** for example has an [assertion](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/move.h#L87) to fail early in this case:

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr _Tp&&
    forward(typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type&& __t) noexcept
    {
      static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<_Tp>::value, "template argument"
            " substituting _Tp is an lvalue reference type");
      return static_cast<_Tp&&>(__t);
    }
```